# Can't import the cx_Oracle module unless I'm using an interactive shell

Tags: python, cx-oracle

When using Python on an interactive shell I'm able to import the cx_Oracle file with no problem. Ex:

```
me@server~/ $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>>
```

As you can see, importing works without a hitch. However, when I try to run a Python script doing the same thing, I get an error:

```
me@server~/ $ sudo script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/script.py", line 19, in <module>
      import cx_Oracle
ImportError: No module named "cx_Oracle'
```

Here is the important section from script.py:

```
# 16 other lines above here
# Imports
import sys
import cx_Oracle
import psycopg2
...
```

I'm befuddled here. Other pertinent information is the server I'm running is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (upgraded from 12.04) 64bit. `which python` and `sudo which python` both point to the same location. Also, doing this as root via `sudo su -` gets the same results; import OK from interactive but error from script.

Nothing other than the OS upgrade happened between when this worked and when it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, all. This was a silly on my part. Turns out the script in question was using Python3, and when the server upgraded, Python3 went from being 3.2 version to being 3.4 version.

Once the cx_Oracle module was set up in the 3.4 version, everything worked as expected.

Phil, your final note talking about the shebang was what lead me to discover this, so kudos to you! The reason I didn't mark your response as the answer was because technically it wasn't but led me on the right path.

Cheers!

Comment: In the future, if someone leads you to the solution (for free) after responding with multiple suggestions to what YOUR error was, please upvote and post the resolution in either thankyou comment or your original question.  Not in your "own" answer that brings no further insights to the problem.  

Hint: you get a badge for your first accepted answer (not your own i think)

Comment: Phil, I tried to up-vote your assistance, but lack reputation. Which is now even lower, thanks. :) I can only do what the system allows and meant no insult. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

sudo starts a new bash environment which is then pointing to a different python executable (different installed modules).

You can verify this with `which python` and `sudo which python`

**EDIT:** so if they point to the same executable, then you should look at sys.path to find differences.  In both environemnts you can:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
sudo python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
```

Look for differences.  If there are none:

A common error in import situations like this is that python will **first** look at the local dir.  So if you happen to be running python and importing something what is found locally (i.e. cx_Oracle is a subdir of your current location), you will get an import error if you change directories.

Final note:  I have assumed here that the shbang of the script.py points to the same executable as `which python`. That is, that `python script.py` and `script.py` return the same error.

Comment: Phil, thanks for that. `which python` and `sudo which python` both point to the same executable. I'll modify my post with that info.